# Tkinter - portion of background transparent

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using MacOS Catalina.

I would like my Tkinter window to only be transparent within a set area.
For instance, I would like to define a 500x500 pixels area and only that area should be transparent, not the entire app...

Any idea how I can do this?

Also, why are the menu bar and the controls transparent?

Sample code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.wait_visibility(root)
root.wm_attributes('-alpha',.3)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Not possible as far as I know. The menubar and controls are transparent because the MacOS window manager was told by tkinter to set the window's opacity to 0.3.

Comment: @scotty3785 aaah, the joys of trying to do dev work on a Mac ^^

Comment: MacOS does have some severe tkinter limitations but you wouldn't be able to specify a small area to be transparent on Window/Linux either.